# High Score in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am totally broke with the high score leaderboard in android... I want to display the top five high scores in the game.. How can I do it... I have the scores and names stored in the database... What should I do next ?

I have this code for the sorting of scores...

```
Collections.sort(scoreList);

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        highScoreList.add(scoreList.get(i));
    }

    return highScoreList;


    }
```

I am looking for the possiblity of sorting it descending and getting the first five records.. Another question, if that's happen, how can I compare the score if it belongs to the high score?

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing?

Comment: Right now, I am able to get all the scores...

Comment: You can in your query sort by score and set the limit to 5.

Comment: how can I set the limit to 5 ?

Comment: If your scores are on database just do a query and get all the scores like this: SELECT score FROM SCORETABLES ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;

Comment: ok.. I got it! But how can I check if the score reaches the top 5, because the user will enter his/her name for storage...

Comment: Sorry for the question.. I am just a newbie... It's for a project..

Comment: The query is sorted by highest score to lowest score, so the first 5 scores are the top 5. You now have to take care of the case where several users tie for the top scores.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. I appreciate it even though this question has many down votes.. thanks a lot, it helps me a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tobiel said if your data is stored in your database a query will be much better. However, if you need to do it in code you should modify your Collection sort.

If in your scoreList you have a collection of Score objects you can compare their scores like this:

```
    Collections.sort(scoreList, new Comparator<Score>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Score score1, Score score2){
            if(score1.getScore() < score2.getScore())
                return -1;
            else if(score1.getScore() > score2.getScore())
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    });
```

Then when you execute your for loop they will be organized by the highest scores.